# missing images after url rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am rewriting the URL from `example.com/service.php?p_id=1&s_id=seo` to `example.com/1/seo/`. The rule is given below:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /services\.php\?p_id=([^&\s]+)&s_id=([^&\s]+) [NC]    
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ services.php?p_id=$1&s_id=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

On the page `service.php` I use `base href="/"` for absolute path. Now, on some pages images is missing. How do I fix this problem? The page in question can be found at  http://www.example.com/packages.php

Comment: Try using absolute path for image paths.

Comment: i had been try sir ...but there is a problem on packages.php now ,absolute path has been fix the problem on service.php but not works for packages.php and one more thing is that now m not accessing my admin module due to this path problem

Comment: But above rule is only impacting `/service` URLs. Do you have other rules too?

Comment: and other rule i have in htaccess....# Redirect non-www to www:

Comment: @ankit.rana please update your question instead of adding comments. BTW the images generate a redirect loop. You can troubleshoot by enabling rewrite log. Please see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog (if you are using Apache version 2.2, or the version you are using).

Comment: @anubhava can u guide me 1 more time...

Comment: I make some changes on the role that u provide me @anubhava ...see the udated rule above

Comment: Now the image problem is solved but m not accessing my admin module when i trying to access http://www.magickeyinfotech.com/_admin the page automatically redirects to http://www.magickeyinfotech.com/_admin/index.php....how to fix it ...

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /services\.php\?p_id=([^&\s]+)&s_id=([^&\s]+) [NC]    
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ services.php?p_id=$1&s_id=$2 [QSA,L]
```

And **make sure there are no other rules** besides this.

Comment: now i changing the whole paths like this <?php if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']!=='localhost') { echo '<base href="/">';} ?>    if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']!=='localhost') { echo '<base src="/">';} ?>       Is it right or wong....

Comment: Another problem now m facing is, when i use the rule given by u for another url like example.com/about-us.php?p_id=1&s_id=2 and for example.com/it-training.php?p_id=1&s_id=2  ....then the url redirects as example.com/1/2/index.php.....while the rule working properly for the file services.php.........give ur opinion...

Comment: That looks like a different problem that this question. Please create a new question and I will attend it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved !

Give Full path to the src attribute of img Tag and href attribute of  tag.

For Example :

```
Use <img src="http://www.magickeyinfotech.com/images/magickey-infotech-logo.png"> Insetad Of <img src="images/magickey-infotech-logo.png">
```